# Multi store setup with sub domains, MAGE_RUN_CODE not working

Tags: magento2

After reading some articles to setup multi store, I have created a new directory containing index.php and .htaccess files along with symlinks for **pub**, **var** and **generated** folders.

Here is updated index.php code:

```
$params= $_SERVER;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'b2b';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

For some reasons this has not been working, I also tried this code in index.php of root directory.

I'm trying to debug it but couldn't find any reference of these "MAGE_RUN_CODE" and "MAGE_RUN_TYPE" keys in magento.

I'm wondering How magento is handling this store switching from these keys in $_SERVER attribute.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have multiple stores or websites?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Multiple websites.